# How to exclude a specific warning while treating warnings as errors in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have set VS 2010 to treat all warnings as errors in C# projects.

[image]

I want a specific warning to be excluded when compiler treats warnings as errors.
Is there any way to do this?

With the options available it does not seem possible.

Comment: Do you mean you still want the warning to be present, but only *as* a warning?

Comment: Yes, I want to exclude just one particular warning from being treated as error.